# navigate method for web browser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, windows-phone

I created a web browser user control, which I have added to a page of my windows phone application. How do I define a navigate method for it?

I have this

```
private void navigate(string urlstring)
{
}
```

it gets the URL from another page as querystring

Comment: Did you inherit from the WebBrowser class?

Comment: I created a new class, and then added a User Control on which I have a web browser control. So I need to define a navigate method for it, because I have placed that user control on a page.

Answer (score 0):

webBrowser.Navigate (new Uri (htmlPath, UriKind.Relative));